# Return type of template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, decltype

**Info:**

I'm currently trying to learn template metaprogramming (by following [this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Template-Metaprogramming-Concepts-Techniques-Beyond/dp/0321227255/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1340095708&sr=8-1)). One useful example they give is for dimensional analysis. I implemented it as in the book and everything was fine; [see here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/mpl/doc/tutorial/representing-dimensions.html).

My problem is however, I want to use the dimensional analysis framework with mixed types. By this I mean you could have say a scalar with dimensions of mass multiplying a vector with dimensions of acceleration to give a vector force. As it stands in the the link they only work with the same type `T` for input and output of all operations.

I have a 3-vector class which has all the necessary operations for multiplying with/dividing by scalars, etc. so I would like to do something like

```
quantity<double,mass> m(1.0);
quantity<vect,acceleration> a(vect(0.0,0.0,-9.81));
quantity<vect,force> f = m*a;
```

**First attempt:**

To acheive this I tried exending the examples form the book to handle two different types as inputs to `operator*` and `operator/` however I hit a wall when it comes to the return type.

I know here the return type of `double * vect` is `vect` but if they are the other way around `vect * double` it is still a `vect`. Worse; in principle the return type could be anything. So I want a way to extend the `operator*` to something like

```
template<class T1, class T2, class Dim1, class Dim2>
quantity<X, typename boost::mpl::transform<Dim1,Dim2,boost::mpl::plus<_1,_2> >::type>
operator*(const quantity<T1,Dim1>& q1, const quantity<T2,Dim2>& q2)
{
    return quantity<X,
                    typename boost::mpl::transform<Dim1,Dim2,boost::mpl::plus<_1,_2> >::type>
                   (q1.value()*q2.value());
}
```

where `X` is the return type of `q1.value()*q2.value()` and is deduced at compile time. I tried simply adding another template class `T3` to the signature and having it return `T3` but it seems it cannot deduce what `T3` should be.

**Second attempt:**

Next I tried using `decltype` as follows

```
template<class T1, class T2>
struct return_type
{
    auto mult_f(const T1& a, const T2& b)->decltype(a*b){return a*b;}
    typedef decltype(mult_f) type;
};

template<class T1, class T2, class Dim1, class Dim2>
quantity<typename return_type<T1,T2>::type, typename boost::mpl::transform<Dim1,Dim2,boost::mpl::plus<_1,_2> >::type>
operator*(const quantity<T1,Dim1>& q1, const quantity<T2,Dim2>& q2)
{
    return quantity<typename return_type<T1,T2>::type,
                    typename boost::mpl::transform<Dim1,Dim2,boost::mpl::plus<_1,_2> >::type>
                   (q1.value()*q2.value());
}
```

However this throws a multitude of incomprehensible compiler errors.

**Question:**

My question is then, am I using `decltype` in the correct way but missing some syntax e.g. a `typename` specifier somewhere? Or; is it even possible to do this this way and if not how is it possible to compute the return type of a function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so first the type `return_type<T1,T2>::type` is not what you seem to be expecting but is the type of a method, namely `T3 (return_type::*)(const T1&, const T2&)` with `T3` being the type you are expecting. If you want to use an intermediate class, you can use:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct return_type
{
  typedef decltype(std::declval<T1>()*std::declval<T2>()) type;
};
```

But you could also use directly `decltype(T1()*T2())` to get the type of the product.

**Edit**: I edited the code with the suggestion of ildjarn, so no need for default-constructible types. Just don't forget to include `<utility>`

Comment: Yeah, I could tell from the compiler output that I was getting the whole function signature. I don't know why I was complicating things so much, your example compiles fine :) Default constructor requirement is not a problem for me here.

Comment: @Dan: note that the book was written prior to C++11 and `decltype` / `auto` availability, which made things **much** more complicated.

Comment: Replace `decltype(T1()*T2())` with `decltype(std::declval<T1>()*std::declval<T2>())` and you no longer require default constructibility.